# How to write Text with someother letter in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to write text with certain pattern,like suppose i want to write A with a's.Can anybody suggest how to achieve this in Qt.I got clue with plugandpaint example in Qt and  that is actually painting on painter,but i want to draw a text with given letter.
Please help me.

Comment: Actually i want to generate bmp image,from painter class.Is it possible to generate with the approach u have suggested?

Comment: Do you mean when you type the letter 'A', it would be constructed of small 'a's, or do you want a brush of the letter 'a' with which you can draw the letter 'A'?

Comment: @Merlin Yup..,i want  when i type letter A ,it should be constructed of small a's..and that too i want that one as bmp image.

Comment: how those small `a`s should be placed when generating the big `A`? Can it be an even pattern, something like grid or honeycomb (something like ASCII art)? Or should those small `a` flows lines of big `A`? First version should be easy, second is quite complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like that?

[image]

```
QBrush generate_letter_brush(QString text, QFont font) {
  QFontMetrics font_metrics(font);
  QPixmap pixmap(font_metrics.boundingRect(text).size());
  pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
  QPainter painter(&pixmap);
  painter.setFont(font);
  painter.drawText(pixmap.rect(),text);
  painter.end();
  return QBrush(pixmap);
}

QImage image(QSize(200, 200), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
image.fill(QColor(200, 255, 200));
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setFont(QFont("", 80));
QBrush brush = generate_letter_brush("a", QFont("", 1));
painter.setPen(QPen(brush, 1));
painter.drawText(image.rect(), "A");
painter.end();
image.save(filename, "BMP"); //save
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image)); //or display
```

Comment: I was planing give similar code, but your code is much better.

Comment: @Parvel When i was compiling your code i am getting problem near image.fill().

Comment: What kind of problem? Any details?

Comment: I am getting error like no matching function for call to 'QImage::fill(QColor)'.so i kept like this     image.fill(qRgb(200, 255, 200));
But i am not getting image like what you gave.I thought of giving whatever image i got but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: `QImage::fill(QColor)` was introduced in Qt 4.8. How old is your Qt version?